# Start different applications on second, third and fourth monitor

Tags: debian, xorg, multi-monitor

I've read some questions about running an application on the second monitor but none of the suggested options has worked for me. Besides that, I'm trying to run different applications no only in the second but also in the third and fourth monitor.

I've tried

```
export DISPLAY=:0.1
export DISPLAY=:0.2
export DISPLAY=:0.3
export DISPLAY=:0.4
export DISPLAY=:1.1
export DISPLAY=:1.2
export DISPLAY=:1.3
export DISPLAY=:1.4
```

But none of them worked. Only

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

works for monitor 1

However I found out that 'export DISPLAY:0' is relative to the monitor the mouse is located in. So if the mouse is in monitor 4 and I run 'export DISPLAY=:0' followed by, let say, 'eog image.jpg' it runs on that same monitor.

Here is my running xorg.conf file. Perhaps someone can get some usefull information from it. It was generated by

```
    # nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 304.64  (pbuilder@cake)  Wed Nov  7 10:04:06 UTC 2012

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 304.48  (buildd@murphy)  Wed Sep 12 11:32:28 UTC 2012

Section "ServerLayout"

    #Screen      4  "Screen4" RightOf "Screen3"
    #Screen      5  "Screen5" RightOf "Screen4"
    #Screen      6  "Screen6" RightOf "Screen5"
    #Screen      7  "Screen7" RightOf "Screen6"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    Screen      3  "Screen3" RightOf "Screen2"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath      "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath        "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
    FontPath        "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "record"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "dri2"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics LG TV"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     58.0 - 62.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics LG TV"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     58.0 - 62.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics LG TV"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     58.0 - 62.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor3"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics LG TV"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     58.0 - 62.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor4"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics LG TV"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     58.0 - 62.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection



Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection



Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1920x1080 +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_60_0 +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_60_1 +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_60_2 +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_30 +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_24 +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_60i +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_60i_0 +0+0; DFP-0: 1360x768 +0+0; DFP-0: 1360x768_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x1024_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x720 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x720_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x720_60_0 +0+0; DFP-0: 1152x864 +0+0; DFP-0: 1152x864_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 720x480 +0+0; DFP-0: 720x480_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480_60_0 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480_60_1 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1920x1080 +0+0; DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1920x1080 +0+0; DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen3"
    Device         "Device3"
    Monitor        "Monitor3"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1920x1080 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection


Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

Comment: What does `echo $DISPLAY` shows on different screens?

Comment: it shows :0.0 on all four screens

Comment: Are you using `Gnome`, `Kde`, `awesome`, other windows manager ?

Comment: gnome-shell (aka gnome3), but I could change if needed.

Comment: Take a look, as GHugo mentioned, at awesome: http://awesome.naquadah.org/ . It's not a specific solution for your problem, but does seem to offer capabilities to do what you want perhaps a bit more easily.

Comment: I'll try awesome sometime soon, but right now I only need a script to start a different slideshow on each monitor. It's for a restorant and they'll show the menu and stuff like that but there are 4 different menus and each one needs to be shown on a different screen.

Comment: It looks like you have four X-sessions instead of one. Something is wrong with your setup. Try to take off xinerama (as I understand, the problem is exactly in xinerama, you must take it off if you want different screens to have different numbers)!